# eclipse mingw cmake path

Tags: eclipse, path, cmake

I get the following when trying to build a makefile in eclipse neon:

> Error: Program "make" not found in PATH

followed by my full path, which begins

> Error: Program "make" not found in PATH PATH=[C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_141/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_141/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_141/lib/amd64;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;

(it continues after this...)

However, cmake is definitely present in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin.

How can I fix this so eclipse is using the cmake.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is looking for `make` program not `cmake`. To install `make` on MSYS2 use the command `pacman -S make`. CMake is a build system generator that creates Makefiles for you. But it does not build the Makefiles itself it uses an installed `make` for that.

Comment: In that case, I'm looking to install make via Msys2?